# Having time waiting in C++ programs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, fltk

I read [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=programming%20principle%20and%20practice&pg=PA583#v=onepage&q&f=true) book. For graphics I installed [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) on my compiler, MS visual studio 2012. The machine I'm using is MS Windows 7.
I have read that book until chapter 17 and I haven't studied any method for waiting. By waiting I mean executing a statement, making the system to wait for a while, and executing second statement.

In the following there is a simple example that draws two shapes on the window. The graphics libraries used for the book are [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/).

For example in this code I have two `circles` with two different positions and different radiuses.
I want to attach first `circle` (`c1`), than wait one second, detach the `c1` and attach the `c2` this time. What is simplest method for waiting for one second of time (or more) please?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GUI.h>
using namespace Graph_lib;

//---------------------------------

class Test : public Window {

public:
    Test(Point p, int w, int h, const string& title):
        Window(p, w, h, title),
        quit_button(Point(x_max()-90,20), 60, 20, "Quit", cb_quit),
        c1(Point(100,100), 50),
        c2(Point(300,200), 100) {
            attach(quit_button);
            attach(c1);
            attach(c2);
    }

private:
    Circle c1, c2;

    Button quit_button;

    void quit() { hide(); }
    static void cb_quit(Address, Address pw) {reference_to<Test>(pw).quit();}
};

//------------------

int main()  {
        Test ts(Point(300,250), 800, 600, "Test"); 
        return gui_main();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using c++11:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

Otherwise use the Windows function Sleep.

And if you want to wait without blocking the main thread you can use std::async:

```
#include <future>

// in your Test's constructor
std::async([&]()
{
    attach(quit_button);
    attach(c1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    attach(c2);
});
```

That might not be working though since I don't know much about the library you're using.

Comment: I added that code between `attach(c1)` and `attach(c2)` and also included <chrono> header. But I got 4 errors. One of them _Error 8 error C3083: 'this_thread': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test_4\test_4\test_4.cpp 18_.

Comment: Thanks. I added it and the code could be running. But it's not what I wanted. This method acts just like Sleep(1000). Please read the comments of below answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [callbacks](http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/example2.html) to put a delay into drawing.  The [add_timeout](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl.html#a23e63eb7cec3a27fa360e66c6e2b2e52) method in the FLTK allows you to set a timer that will be called once after a delay.  In the callback you can attach the `c2`.

By sleeping in between `attach(c1)` and `attach(c2)` does not pass control back to the GUI thread to allow it to draw anything.  By using the `add_timeout` control is passed back to the GUI thread so it can draw `c1`.  One second later your callback will be called where you can attach `c2`.

```
// The function that will be called after the timeout.  The testWindow object will be of type Test*
void callback(void* testWindow)
{
    Test* t = reinterpret_cast<Test*>(testWindow);
    t->doCallback();
}

class Test : public Window 
{
public:
    Test(Point p, int w, int h, const string& title):
        Window(p, w, h, title),
        quit_button(Point(x_max()-90,20), 60, 20, "Quit", cb_quit),
        c1(Point(100,100), 50),
        c2(Point(300,200), 100)
    {
        attach(quit_button);
        attach(c1);
        // Setup the timeout and pass a pointer to the Test window to the call back
        Fl::add_timeout(1.0, callback, this);
    }

    // Method that is called by callback() and will attach c2
    void doCallback()
    {
        attach(c2);
    }

    // rest of class
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But they are all new for me. And I'm novice. Can you make a simple code that make the system to wait for one second?

Comment: @s.r.a I've added a code sample, but I don't have FLTK so it might not work immediately.

Comment: I have installed FLTK and it works fine for me. Thank you very much. I test the code and aware of the results.

Comment: I changed `FI::` (capital i) to `Fl::` (small l). and also put the `void callback(void* testWindow)` body below of the class but again got 4 errors. one of the is:  _Error 8 error C3867: 'Fl_Widget::callback': function call missing argument list; use '&Fl_Widget::callback' to create a pointer to member c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test_4\test_4\test_4.cpp 22
_

Comment: The callback will need to be declared above where it is used (but can be defined below if needs be).  I've fixed the case error in the sample.

Comment: OK but 4 errors (while the `callback` body is in below of the class) were apart from that case error. First one is above and this is the second error: _Error 9 error C2065: 'c2' : undeclared identifier c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test_4\test_4\test_4.cpp 43
_

Comment: That reference to `c2` in `callback()` shouldn't have been in the code, my mistake.  I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: Bravo. You also removed two of the errors. But still there are two: **1)** _Error 8 error C3867: 'Fl_Widget::callback': function call missing argument list; use '&Fl_Widget::callback' to create a pointer to member c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test_4\test_4\test_4.cpp 19_ **And 2)** _ 9 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "Test::callback" matches the required type c:\Users\CS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_4\test_4\test_4.cpp 19_

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Sleep function, which takes milliseconds:

```
Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Sleep(1000) doesn't let the system to show the `c1` circle. I want to see first circle then after one second see another one.

Comment: @s.r.a So show the `c1` circle, *then* `Sleep(1000)`, then show the next circle.

Comment: Sleep() takes the window to the comma and doesn't let the `c1` or any prior shapes to be seeable.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, `Sleep` isn't the answer, because you need to let control pass back to the system while waiting, or else the window won't get updated.

What you need is a timeout. FLTK provides `add_timeout`:

http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/Fl.html#Fl.add_timeout